# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'keypress': object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, keypress, keydown

I am trying to use jQuery code like below to execute some code on keypress for text box but I am getting error. Could you please help me here. I have even tried with keydown but facing same issue.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        textarea.ex1 { background-color: white; width: 610px; height: 310px; overflow: Scroll; }
        #outer {  width:100%; text-align: center;} .inner { display: inline-block; }
        body { background-color: gray; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="screen" class="ex1"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="command" style="width: 480px; height=600px;"/>
<script>
    $("#command").keydown(function(event){
        alert('Before keycode validation cond');
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        alert('After keycode validation');
        if(keycode == '13')
        {
            alert('ENTER key selected');
            $.get('Servlet3', function(response) {
                alert(response);
                appendResponse(response);
            });
            appendCommand();
        }
    });
    function appendCommand() {
        alert('appending command');
        document.getElementById('screen').textContent = document.getElementById('screen').textContent + document.getElementById('command').value;
    }
    function appendResponse(response) {
        alert('appending response');
        document.getElementById('screen').textContent = document.getElementById('screen').textContent + response;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Provide your HTML also

Comment: I tried to test your code with IE 11 browser and found that it is working fine. Here is the testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/pdvS1kF1/138.gif Can you inform us which version of iE you are using for this test? also, inform us on which line you got this error? It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I am running above code on IE11 and getting error from below line. 
$("#command").keydown(function(event){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is working fine. Check the fiddle below. I just disabled the comments in code.

```js
function onKeyDown(event) {
        //alert('Before keycode validation cond');
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        //alert('After keycode validation');
        if(keycode == '13')
        {
            //alert('ENTER key selected');
            $.get('Servlet3', function(response) {
                //alert(response);
                appendResponse(response);
            });
            appendCommand();
        }
    }
    if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, true);
        } else if (document.attachEvent) { // IE 
            // alert(document); You can test this in IE
            document.attachEvent("onkeydown", onKeyDown);
        } else {
            document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, true);
        }
    function appendCommand() {
        //alert('appending command');
        document.getElementById('screen').textContent = document.getElementById('screen').textContent + document.getElementById('command').value;
    }
    function appendResponse(response) {
        //alert('appending response');
        document.getElementById('screen').textContent = document.getElementById('screen').textContent + response;
    }
```

```css
textarea.ex1 { background-color: white; width: 610px; height: 310px; overflow: Scroll; }
        #outer {  width:100%; text-align: center;} .inner { display: inline-block; }
        body { background-color: gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="screen" class="ex1"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="command" style="width: 480px; height=600px;"/>
```

Comment: Yeah its working when I am trying to run this from eclipse. But getting error while trying on IE.

Comment: Do you mean in internet explorer? What error you are getting in the console?

Comment: Yes Internet Explorer only. Below is the error.  SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'keypress': object is null or undefined

Comment: I have updated my answer to handle the IE. Please check out my updated answer. This should work in IE as well as other browsers.

Comment: There is a known issue with `keydown` event for IE.

Comment: Your Java Script code working fine. Thanks Mayank Patel

Answer (score 0):

I am not available with IE 9 browser so I try to test with **Document mode IE 9** in IE 11 browser.

Your code worked fine in it. Here is the test result.

[image]

If you are still getting an error then I suggest you upgrade to IE 11 browser. IE 9 is a too old version and at present, it is out of support scope.